# Passing Generic type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a method

```
 public Queryable Query<T>()
 {
 }
```

now can i call the method by dynamically creating generic argument T.

saomething like this

```
 public Queryable Query<T>()
 {

    Query<OtherT>();
 }
```

otherT could be a type of a property in T.

Thanks,

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is or what you are trying to do, so you're gonna have to put a little more effort in to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public Queryable Query<T>()
{
    MethodInfo method = GetType().GetMethod("Query");

    return (Queryable)method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(OtherT)).Invoke(this, null);
}
```

This will automatically close the `Query<T>` method of `typeof(OtherT)`. You can provide the type you require here.

Answer (score 4):

You can call generic methods dynamically using reflection by first getting the generic method definition (with [`Type.GetMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethod.aspx)), then calling [`MakeGenericMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx) and supplying the type arguments, then calling [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx). However, you haven't given us enough information to go on in order to give you an example.

Comment: Thanks jon, i tried using MakeGeneric method and call through Invoke method and it worked perfectly, thank u so much

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The generic parameter type needs to be known at compile time. That's why we say that when we use generics it is a strongly typed code, because the types are known in advance. When the type is known only at runtime you cannot use it as generic parameter.